# Get extension from file created from Base64 string

Tags: java, base64

This function is used to convert a Base64 String to file, but the problem here is the data only read then write to the file, I cannot define what type of that file is (example: .png, .jpeg, .pdf). Help me to solve it!

```
public static File convertBase64ToFile(String str, String filePath, String fileName) {
        // Note preferred way of declaring an array variable
        File file = new File(filePath + fileName);
        byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
        try {
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

For example, the file_content is "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB...". I want to get the file name with its extension like "image.jpg", and the same with pdf or png without creating the new file, only get the name and extension (I cannot use the apache tika for some reasons).

Comment: I'm puzzled. Are you saying the extension is missing in parameter `filename`?

Comment: What I understood is that you want to get the name and the file extension from the Base64 String because it is not given to you via the filename parameter. This is not possible. The best you can do is to read the first characters and compare then to known file headers to guess the file extension. For a pdf file the first four characters will be '%PDF'